# The MCITP: SharePoint Administrator 2010 certification (70-668) will be retired on January 31, 2014

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, certificate, certification, 70-667, 70-331

Have read on [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/sharepoint-certification.aspx) site that " SharePoint Administrator 2010 certification (70-668) will be retired on January 31, 2014."

Does it mean that these certification does not have any value after January 31, 2014 !!!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you will no longer be able to get certified towards these exams. But it doesn't mean that your certificate is no longer valid. As far as I know, Microsoft Exams are valid for three years from the date you took them, even if they are retired.

What it does mean though is that when that period of three years have passed, you will not be able to take the exam again on the next version i.e. SharePoint 2013.

[image]

Reference: [Exams scheduled to retire](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/retired-certification-exams.aspx)

Within the SharePoint community, there is an ongoing debate to make Microsoft change their mind on these retired exams discussed in Wictor Wiléns article [Microsoft Advanced Certification (MCA, MCSM, MCM) - the end of an era](http://www.wictorwilen.se/microsoft-advanced-certification-mca-mcsm-mcm---the-end-of-an-era).